# How to hide option panel when submitting form?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have this form that has this **dropdown** multiselect and I want to be able to hide **options panel** when clicking on **Submit** button. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing please? Thanks a lot in advance!

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here's my code:

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="registrationStatus" [defaultLabel]="someText" [showHeader]="false"></p-multiSelect>
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-input-multiselect-sscfyj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: what do you mean by `options panel` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the reference of select box and show and hide as required -

```
<form>
   <p-multiSelect #status (click)="status.show()" [options]="registrationStatus" [defaultLabel]="someText" [showHeader]="false"></p-multiSelect><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

   <button (click)="status.hide()">Submit2</button>
</form>
```

working copy is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-input-multiselect-hjq2qf

Here is the another version - https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-input-multiselect-bzip3o

Comment: Use this demo link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-input-multiselect-hjq2qf

Comment: Sigh it works, but can you please add the functionality using the hideOptionsPanel function in the component? Thank you so much!

Comment: btw you can do the same in ts file also. Refer this demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-input-multiselect-bzip3o

Answer (score 0):

You need to use hidden attribute. Add hidden attribute to multi select tag.

```html
<p-multiSelect [hidden]="hidePanel" [options]="registrationStatus" [defaultLabel]="someText" [showHeader]="false">
```

Now you need to set hidePanel to true, so as to apply hidden attribute. So, when submit is clicked:

```js
hidePanel: boolean = false;

hideOptionsPanel() {
  //How to hide options panel
  alert("Let's hide options panel");
  this.hidePanel = true;
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-input-multiselect-e2t3pp?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: it doesn't work. it seems to be hiding everything including the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't have enough points to comment on Sunil's answer. So, I am writing it here. you need to add these things to your ts file.

```
@ViewChild('status') status;
hideOptionsPanel(){
 //How to hide options panel
 this.status.hide();
}
```

and in your .html file

```
<button (click)="hideOptionsPanel()">Submit2</button>
```